# Does $Z=X+Y$ imply $Z-Y=X$ when $X,Y,Z$ are random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I was recently working through someone else's proof involving Gaussian processes $\{X_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{\epsilon_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$, where $\epsilon_t$ was iid Gaussian noise and $X_t$ was a random walk:

$$
X_t = X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
$$

and another processes $\{Z_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ was defined as

$$
Z_t = X_t + \phi_t
$$

with $\phi_t$ another source of iid Gaussian noise.  In their proof, they started with the first equation above and made the substitution $X_{t-1} = Z_{t-1} - \phi_{t-1}$ to get

$$
\begin{align}
X_t &= X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t \\
X_t &= (Z_{t-1} - \phi_{t-1}) + \epsilon_t &&(*)
\end{align}
$$

And that seems perfectly fine.  But I have what *feels* like a very stupid question.  *Was* that substitution valid?  If not, what assumptions make it valid?

---

I ask because they came to an incorrect result, which is why I was working through the proof in the first place, and I could find no mistake anywhere.  So now I'm testing even my most basic assumptions.  I've tried to figure this out on my own, but I'm just not sure.

The following example is what makes me wonder if the substitution was indeed valid, but I suspect I'm making a basic mistake.  Let $X$ and $Y$ be r.v. with

$$
X=
\begin{cases}
-1, p=0.1\\
1, p=0.9
\end{cases}
$$

$$
Y=
\begin{cases}
-1, p=0.5\\
1, p=0.5
\end{cases}
$$

Then

$$
Z=X+Y = 
\begin{cases}
-2, p=0.05\\
0, p=.5 \\
2, p=0.45
\end{cases}
$$

Perhaps I'm missing something, but it appears the r.v. $Z-Y$ can take values in  $\{\pm 1, \pm 3\}$.  So $Z-Y \neq X$.  And we can conclude that $Z=X+Y$ does not necessarily imply $X=Z-Y$, and we cannot make the substitution in $(*)$.  ...But that feels very incorrect, and I'd really appreciate having my mistakes pointed out.

Comment: The incorrect part is that $X$ and $Z$ are not independent. Indeed if $Z=-2$ then we know that $X=-1$. The fact that $Z-Y=X$ is in general correct.

Comment: Thank you @P.Quinton, that's quite reassuring.  So it seems the substitution made in $(*)$ was valid after all, right?  There hasn't been any subtle change made in the dependence structure of the r.v. involved?

Comment: @P.Quinton - I have to disagree with your assertion that $Z- Y = X$ is in general correct. You can see my answer below for my claim that it's more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is a full answer (because I'm a bit confused too), but your question seems to hinge on whether or not the random variable $$ X + Y - Y$$ is the same as the random variable $X$, (i.e. "has the same distribution as").

And I think this comes down to some ambiguity with the way we write random variables. If you use the same letter twice, we can't tell if you mean the identical sample drawn from that same variable, or a new instance from a different variable with the same distribution.

In the first part of your question, when they wrote $X_{t-1} = Z_{t-1} - \phi_{t-1}$, it looks like the intention was that $\phi_{t-1}$ meant the identical $\phi_{t-1}$ used to define $Z_{t-1}$, so the cancellation was valid. But in the second half, where you wrote $Z-Y$,  you were "re-instantiating" $Y$, i.e. getting values from a different, though identically distributed, instance of $Y$, and so $Y - Y \ne 0$.

(If you program in C++, there is an analogy with assigning a pointer vs. calling a copy constructor, but it's not worth get getting into if those terms aren't immediately meaningful to you.)

Comment: I disagree, a random variable is not defined in terms of distribution but as a mapping from the outcome set $\Omega$ to anything, as such $X+Y-Y$ is defined as the mapping from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$ that is $\omega\to X(\omega)+Y(\omega)-Y(\omega)=X(\omega)$ so that $X-Y+Y=X$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may give rise to criticism due to it's technical incorrectness, nevertheless I think it is clearly more correct then the current only answer and I am happy to remove it when there is a better answer.

When you work with probabilities, you typically define a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb P)$ where $\Omega$ represents the the universe, $\Sigma$ is a set containing subsets of $\Omega$ (technically it is supposed to be a $\sigma$-algebra) and $\mathbb P$ is a mapping from $\Sigma$ to $[0,1]$ that satisfies several properties.

The confusion here is that a random variable is defined as a mapping from $\Omega$ to some set (again some more technicalities missing here) and not in terms of it's probability distribution, indeed there is no dependence on $\mathbb P$. So when we deal with real random variable $X$ and $Y$ we mean to have mappings $\omega\to X(\omega)$ and $\omega\to Y(\omega)$, now the sum of those is also a mapping from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $\omega\to X(\omega)+Y(\omega)$. Subtracting $Y$ is again a mapping defined by $\omega\to X(\omega)+Y(\omega)-Y(\omega)=X(\omega)$ so we have that $X+Y-Y=X$, and all of this is independent of the probability distribution (that are functions of $\mathbb P$).

I hope this clarifies a bit, I am aware of some of the missing things. I would suggest reading the Wikipedia page of random variables and probability spaces to get the clear (and less arguable) definition, this may take a bit of time though.

Comment: I’m familiar with the measure theoretic definition of random variables, so explanation in those terms is great actually.  I think the difference you are clarifying is the difference between equality in distribution vs. pointwise equality in the actual from sample space.  Am I interpreting correctly?

Comment: Well, the random variable is always defined with respect to $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ only. And in that regard it is very clear that it is defined from sample space. At that stage $\mathbb P$ doesn't ever matter.

Comment: I agree that a $\Sigma$-measurable function $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be defined only using measurable space $(\Omega, \Sigma)$. But $X$ is only a random variable if the space has some measure $P$. Intuitively, the measure is our source of randomness, so our function $X$ is not a _random_ variable without it.  Requiring a full measure space $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ in the r.v. definition is why [equality in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Equality_in_distribution) is a well-defined question for any two r.v. without further qualification.

Comment: I should clarify - I'm sure you're already completely aware of what I said! The reason I even bring it up is that your answer made me realize that my original question is not very clearly asked.  I invoked random variables $X, Y$ without specifying if share the same sample space $\Omega$, or if they share the same measure space $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$.  And I stated $Z=X+Y$ without specifying the type of equality.  I _think_ all three of those affect the answer.

Comment: Well, I have never seen $A=B$ to mean $A$ have the same distribution as $B$ in this context, also unless you make them independent it also doesn't at all give the joint distribution of them. But as long as you define everything properly it should work, then of course $X+Y$ is independent of $X$ and so $(X+Y)-X \neq X$, also the $+$ operation is no longer associative.

Comment: That’s extremely helpful, thank you.  I searched quite a while for arithmetic properties like the addition nonassociativity you just listed, but could not find anything.