# Question about the nature of random variable sampling

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be a random variable that has uniform distribution from -1 to 1 as it's PDF. What is the PDF of $X \cdot X$ vs $X^2$. How about $E[X^2]$ and $E[X \cdot X]$. If we are sampling one distribution and then squaring the result, that seems to lead to a PDF distributed from 0 to 1, but if we are sampling the distribution twice and multiplying them together, this seems to lead to a PDF from -1 to 1. My main confusion here is if we are sampling two different identically distributed distributions or just one. Is there a way to differentiate between these two situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the notation doesn't help us much here: there's no way to denote the action of drawing a single sample, or to differentiate between the underlying random variable and a single value drawn from that random variable.

So  if you see $X \cdot  X$ you usually have to ask the question you're asking here - "How many times are you sampling in that expression, 1 or 2?". Which is why you don't see that notation used much!

Me, I'm used to seeing the language "$X_1 \cdot X_2$, where $X_i$ are i.i.d. random variables" used to describe the 2 samples situation, and "$X^2$" for the 1 sample situation. [And "i.i.d." is the common abbreviation for "independent identically distributed".]

---

Incidentally, this question reminded me of a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3848492/does-z-xy-imply-z-y-x-when-x-y-z-are-random-variables), where the same ambiguity of "1 sample or 2 samples" lead to similar confusion. And in that case the [similar answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3848492/does-z-xy-imply-z-y-x-when-x-y-z-are-random-variables/3849347#3849347) was ignored, and things went down some other blind end. :-)

Comment: Thank you! this stems from a question on my intro to probability midterm about the distribution of the multiplication of two normal distributions and I was confused that I couldn't actually evaluate the integral that you'd get if you assume sampling two identical normal distributions instead of 1 and squaring.

Comment: Eesh! I hope they didn't use the $X \cdot X$ notation.  Or that your grade wasn't too badly affected.